# construct an unbiased estimator $\hat{\acute{\mu }_k}$ for $\acute{\mu }_k=E[X^k]$

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Problem:
Construct an unbiased estimator $\hat{\acute{\mu }_k}$ for $\acute{\mu }_k=E[X^k]$ for any positive integer k.

(1) show its unbiasedness.

(2) find its variance $var[\hat{\acute{\mu }_k}]$

(3) propose an estimator for $var[\hat{\acute{\mu }_k}]$.

This is a first-year phd econometrics problem. I don't think its too hard to be solved but the question requires an 'unbiased' estimation. Does it really need a h-statistic procedure? Can someone show me the exact proof of this unbiasedness? Thank you so much!

Comment: This site is for Q&A concerning the Mathematica software application and the Wolfram programming language. Your question does not appear to involve either. If it does, please provide the code that you have tried and explain the problems you are having with the code.

Comment: Is this about the software Mathematica or about mathematics? If the latter holds, you should have posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Even if you post this question at some other stack site, they would want to know if it is course work. If it is, then please add a homework tag to it. Also show what you have accomplished so far and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will post on another site. This is not course work but my self-studying material. I will try to post my progress on it.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting parts of this question can in fact be greatly assisted using *Mathematica*, and in a completely general way:

1. By the fundamental expectation result, sample raw moments are unbiased estimators of population raw moments. Using power sum notation, $s_r=\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^r$, we have:  $$E[\frac{s_r}{n}] = \acute{\mu }_r$$

i.e. $\large{\frac{s_r}{n}}$ is an unbiased estimator of the $r^\text{th}$ raw moment.

---

2. Find $\text{Var}[\frac{s_r}{n}]$:

The variance operator denotes  the 2nd Central Moment of $\frac{s_r}{n}$, so the variance of $\frac{s_r}{n}$, expressed in terms of RawMoments of the population is:

[image]

where I am using the *CentralMomentToRaw* function from the mathStatica package for *Mathematica*.

---

3. Propose an unbiased estimator for the variance in point 2.

Answer: the solution in point 2 has two terms.

- An unbiased estimator of $\large{\frac{\acute{\mu }_{2 r}}{n}}$ is given immediately by point 1 as $\large{\frac{s_{2 r}}{n^2}}$.
- An unbiased estimator of $(\acute{\mu}_r)^2$ requires that we find an unbiased estimator of the product of two raw moments. In our text, *Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica*, we call these unbiased estimators of products of raw moments to be PolyRaws. The unbiased estimator of $(\acute{\mu}_r)^2 = \acute{\mu}_{r} \acute{\mu}_{r}$ is given by the PolyRaw function as:

[image]

Putting the two terms together, an unbiased estimator of the variance in point 2 is:

$$\frac{s_{2 r}}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n} \frac{s_r^2-s_{2 r}}{(n-1) n}$$

---

Check that is is unbiased!

Finally, let's check that the result in point 3 really is an unbiased estimator of the variance in point 2. Here we find the 1st Raw Moment (i.e. expectation) of the result in point 3:

[image]

... and all is well (i.e. the expectation of the unbiased estimator in 3 IS the variance in point 2).

Comment: Thank you so much!! Though I am not following your ideas on your answer to (1). The problem is, $E[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i}^r}{n}]\ne \mu_r$. You can check that when r=2: actually $E[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i}^2}{n-1}] = \mu_2$ ! This $E[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i}^r}{n}] = \mu_r$ arguement is true only when n turns to infinity -- this is a large-sample asymptotic property.